# Capital letter in abbreviation for "standard deviation"?

Tags: abbreviations

I need to use an abbreviation for "standard deviation". I know I can use "SD", but today i was asked to use "Std. Dev." instead.

Std. can be used as abbreviation for standard.

**My question is about the second word in the abbreviation. Is it written with an upper-case "D" (Std. Dev.) or a lower- case "d" (Std. dev.)**?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Problems. 'Standard Deviation (often abbreviated as "Std Dev" or "SD") provides an indication of ...' [[Greenbook.org marketing research / how to interpret standard deviation and standard error in survey research.](https://www.greenbook.org/marketing-research/how-to-interpret-standard-deviation-and-standard-error-in-survey-research-03377)]: Capital, but no full stops. But I'd use the one the boss wants when doing my job, and use my own preferred style otherwise.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. There is no one right way to make such abbreviations; such things are a matter of style, not the language itself. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579/16052) appropriate to your audience  and tastes and be consistent in its application.